# Want to undo function after clicking anywhere but the orginal div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have an input that will open when clicked on and close when clicked anywhere on the page except the div itself. I use a function that changes the inputs background color when clicking on the input, but I can't figure out how to "undo" the color change when the user closes the input div by clicking elsewhere on the page.

```js
function makeRed() {
  var p = document.querySelector('input');
  p.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

input[type=text] {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #525252;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF 0%, #464747 #F9F9F9 100%);
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 300px;
}

i {
  position: relative;
  left: -37px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="searchBar">
  <input placeholder='Search...' class='js-search' type="text" onClick="makeRed()">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: might be this is helpfull for u https://jsfiddle.net/ismailfarooq/03raarf9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try yo use **[focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus)** and **[blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur)** event listener

```js
var x = document.querySelector('input');
x.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  this.style.background = 'red';
})
x.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  this.style.background = 'white';
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

input[type=text] {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #525252;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF 0%, #464747 #F9F9F9 100%);
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 300px;
}

i {
  position: relative;
  left: -37px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="searchBar">
  <input placeholder='Search...' class='js-search' type="text">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have never heard of blur before, did the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to end the handler `onfocusout` on the input to call a function when the input is unfocused (when ANYTHING else is clicked or unfocused on mobile)

```
onfocusout="revertColor()"
```

Answer (score 0):

add a blur function to input tag

```
function makeWhite() {
  var p = document.querySelector('input');
    p.style.background = 'white';
}

function makeRed() {
  var p = document.querySelector('input');
    p.style.background = 'red';
}

<body>          
<div class="searchBar">
    <input placeholder='Search...' class='js-search' type="text" onClick="makeRed()" onBlur="makeWhite()">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a JavaScript function, you can achieve the expected output using CSS.

Let us know if anything else you are doing in the function which is affecting the style.

Remove JS function and update your CSS to

```
input[type=text]:focus {
     width: 300px;
     background-color:red;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

input[type=text] {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #525252;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF 0%, #464747 #F9F9F9 100%);
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 300px;
  background-color:red;
}

i {
  position: relative;
  left: -37px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="searchBar">
  <input placeholder='Search...' class='js-search' type="text">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `onfocus` and `onfocusout`

```js
var p = document.querySelector('input');
function makeRed() {
  p.style.background = 'red';
}
function removeRed(){
  p.style.background = 'initial';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="searchBar">
    <input placeholder='Search...' class='js-search' type="text" onfocus="makeRed()" onfocusout="removeRed()">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't select the input every event fire, only select it once. Reset background to its original value before setting to 'red', it may have not been 'initial'.

Comment: I do admit the mistake of multiple instance of the input, I just copied the `onfocus` script, but the 'initial' part is irrelevant. Of course OP can change it to whatever the original color or whatnot, it is just an example

Comment: And please do check the definition of [`initial`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp). I will also appreciate if you @Noface could remove the down-vote, as I have already addressed the issues. *(if you are indeed the down voter, if not disregard the latter part)*

Answer (score -2):

to reset a css property, set it to an empty string:

```js
var p = document.querySelector('input');
function makeRed(el) {
  el.style.background = 'red';
}

function resetBackground(el){
  el.style.background = '';
}
p.addEventListener('click', function(){
  makeRed(this);
}, false);
p.addEventListener('blur', function(){
  resetBackground(this);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

call resetBackground inside a blur event.

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

[blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur)